# NPM Install for Mean.IO frozen at Updating Bower Dependencies

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mean.io

I have successfully downloaded the MEAN stack and created a new app.  However, when I move into the app director and run "npm install", the downloads stop at this line:

```
bootstrap#3.3.6 bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.2.0
    Updating Bower dependencies
```

It has been sitting here for over 1 hour.

What is going on and how do I fix this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hope you solved your problem. In case you didn't, here's what I did to solve that: press CTRL+C to stop the process. You'll then get a notification saying, "Dependencies installed for package i18n." It continues the installation afterwards.
I scrolled up the terminal and found that `bower install` was being run by some post-installation script under the "packages/custom/i18n" folder to install the dependencies for the i18n package just prior to the "freeze". Since the installation went smoothly afterwards, I assume that the dependencies had already been installed and the "freeze" was just a minor hitch in the process.
BTW, re-running `npm install` again goes smoothly without any hitches.

Comment: Cheers mate. Helped me out as well.

Answer (score 0):

The dekarpaulvictor solution worked for me in that I hit CTRL+C and the installation continued. I noticed after the installation got moving again after CTRL+C that it prompted me if I wanted to send usage information to bower. After I answered the prompt, the install continued. When I ran "npm install" again, just as above, it worked fine.